# Segmentation error in DFS

Tags: c, graph, c99

I have written a simple recursion procedure for DFS.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void mydfs(int ROWS, int COLS,char **A,int row, int col, bool **visited){
    static int rowAdjacencyParams[4] = {-1,0,1,0};
    static int colAdjacencyParams[4] = {0,1,0,-1};

    *(*(visited+col)+row) = true;
    //visited[row][col] = true;
    int i,newR,newC;
    for(i = 0;i<4;i++){
        newR = row + rowAdjacencyParams[i];
        newC = col + colAdjacencyParams[i];

        if(((newR >=0) && (newR < ROWS)) && ((newC>=0) && (newC < COLS))){
            /*if((A[newR][newC] == 'X') && !visited[newR][newC]){
                mydfs(ROWS,COLS,A,newR,newC,visited);
            }*/
        }
    }
}

int black(char** A, int n1) {
    int i,j,count = 0; 
    int cols = strlen(A[0]);
    bool visited[n1][cols];

    memset(visited,0,sizeof(visited));


    for(i = 0;i<n1;i++){
        for(j = 0;j<cols;j++){
            if((A[i][j] == 'X') && !visited[i][j]){
                count++;
                mydfs(n1,cols,A,i,j,visited);
            }
        }
    }


    return count;
}
int main(){
    int ROWS = 3;
    int COLS = 7;

    char P[ROWS][COLS]= {"OOOXOOO","OOXXOXO","OXOOOXO"};

    printf("Number of islands = %d",black(P,COLS));
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATED main Function**

However, when I run this it gives me a `segmentation fault` for line `visited[row][col] = true;`. Then I tried to change it to `*(*(visited+col)+row) = true;` but still having the same segmentation fault error. Please explain why am I getting this error.

Comment: `bool visited[n1][cols];`  This is not legal C++.  Also, pick a language -- it's either C++ or C.  I fail to see the `C++` in the code you posted.  If it is C++, using `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` instead of double star pointers could / should have been used

Comment: Also, post a [mcve], meaning to also post a `main` function that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: The array you pass is 2-D, the function argument is double star. `*(*(visited+col)+row) = true;` has no idea what the row length is. I suggest `visited + row*cols + col`, or preferably, define the function argument to match the array you pass.

Comment: [Arrays are not pointers!](/questions/8630054/2d-array-variable-pointer-confusion)  In particular, a 2D array of `char` does not in any way correspond to a `char **`.  This has been well-covered here; I decline to close as a dupe only because I am uncertain whether the question is really about C or about C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have updated with the main function. I think `bool visited[n1][cols]` is valid since I have already included `#include <stdbool.h>`. This supported in C99.

Comment: @user3243499 You tagged the question as C++, and that is not legal in C++.  The rules of C++ explicitly state that arrays are to be declared using compile-time expressions.  What you're probably taking advantage of is a compiler *extension* called "Variable Length Arrays".  Believe me, they are more trouble than they're worth **if** what you're writing is C++.  Instead, use `std::vector`.

Comment: @user3243499, as Paul instructed you already, **pick *one* language**, either C or C++.  Indicate your choice by updating the tags on your question.  Inasmuch as you are now referring to the C99 standard, it seems you probably want C.  Note in particular that variable-length arrays are one of the C features that are not in C++.

Comment: Fyi, `"OOOXOOO"` - that would require **8** characters to store; not 7, when you also account for the terminating nulchar. I'd start by fixing that. Then fix the broken assumption you're making that an array of arrays is equivalent to an array of pointers; they're not.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Does calling the function using `visited[][COLS]` means call by reference or call by value ? Because I want it to be call by reference. Since the `visited` matrix in`main()` function needs to be updated.

Comment: Honestly it is wrong starting with the declaration and initialization of `P` in `main()`, and just goes downhill from there. Variable length arrays are not initializable like that per the standard. By the time you invoke `black(P,COLS)` (which is also wrong, see my prior comment, as I can't say it any clearer than that) it's just further nosed into a mountain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the character data exceeding the array's buffer as pointed out by the comments, beyond that another error is this:

```
int black(char** A, int n1) {
//...
for(i = 0;i<n1;i++){
    for(j = 0;j<cols;j++){
        if((A[i][j] == 'X') && !visited[i][j]){  /* A[i] is out of bounds */
```

The `n1` is passed in as the number of columns, which is 7.  However if you go back to `main`, you have this:

```
int ROWS = 3;
int COLS = 7;

char P[ROWS][COLS]= {"OOOXOOO","OOXXOXO","OXOOOXO"};
printf("Number of islands = %d",black(P,COLS));
```

The `P` array has only 3 rows.  So when the `black` function is called, it is assuming that P has 7 rows, not 3 rows.  This results in the `A` array accessing `A[0]`, `A[1]`, `A[2]`, (good), but then `A[3]`, etc. which is undefined behavior (and in your case, a crash).

So you need to get your column / row logic corrected.

---

I will let you in on a secret.  Since you originally tagged your question as C++, I took the time to change those double stars to `std::vector`, and use the `at()` function to locate the issue.  I know that you've now tagged your question as C99, but I would just like to be aware why tags are important.  I don't know if C99 has this feature of auto-detecting boundary conditions like this.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer and clarifying the `n1` thing. I have made the corrections. Also I have changed `char **A` to `char A[][COLS]` and `bool visited[][COLS]`. Now it is running successfully. But the results it returns is 6. Which is not desired since the number of `4-connected` components is clearly 3. Also I have debugged that `if((A[newR][newC] == 'X') && (visited[newR][newC] == 0))` line is always `false`. It seams like the `visited` array is not getting updated or simply copying a new version of it every time I passed it in  a recursive call.

Comment: The new function call used is `void mydfs(int ROWS, int COLS,char A[][COLS],int row, int col, int visited[][COLS])`

Comment: And I have recursively called it using this statement `mydfs(ROWS,COLS,A,newR,newC,visited);`

Comment: @user3243499 The original question dealt with a segmentation fault, and the answer addresses this.  Since the seg fault is now not happening, the question of why you do not get the correct answer is another separate issue.